# No HTTP triggers found. After successful deployment of Azure Funtions Project (c#)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions BE using C# and I'm using it for quite some time now (already hat multiple successful deploys with no issues and also used the BE in production).

But now all of the sudden, I run into a problem in the deployment process. I use the VS Code Extension "Azure Functions" to deploy my functions. And last time I used it, for some reason, the deployment was successful but it couldn't find any HTTP triggers in my project.

Here the last output from the extension:

```
8:04:59 PM <function-app>: Zip package size: 18.6 MB
8:04:59 PM <function-app>: Updating submodules.
8:04:59 PM <function-app>: Preparing deployment for commit id 'id'.
8:04:59 PM <function-app>: Skipping build. Project type: Run-From-Zip
8:05:00 PM <function-app>: Skipping post build. Project type: Run-From-Zip
8:05:00 PM <function-app>: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
8:05:00 PM <function-app>: Deployment successful.
8:05:05 PM <function-app>: Querying triggers...
8:05:07 PM <function-app>: No HTTP triggers found.
```

Now even after reverting my code the problem persists, which tells me its not a code problem. Also locally Azure Functions can see my HTTP triggers and I can run the project locally with no issues.

The only thing I can think of that was a change was that I added new environment variables into my `local.settings.json`. But I also added these vars in the Azure Portal inside the configuration (as I have done successful previously). And even after removing these vars again the problem persists.

Could there be a bad state of something, that still has these variable and therefore throws an error?

For some additional information here is my local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ClientId": "<clientID>",
    "ClientSecret": "<clientSecret>",
    "TenantId": "<tenantId>",
    "AdminRoleId": "<adminroleid>"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "connectionstring"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 5004,
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

I also tried to just restart my vs code and pc, reinstalled all the extensions and tried an older extension version but the problem persists.

At this point I don't really know what to try next, especially since this message doesn't really give a great insight into the underlying problem. Any Help is very much appreciated and if there is any need of additional information please tell me and I will provide it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: just started having this issue now. Really annoying!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! IM TRYING TO RELEASE MY GOSH DARN GAME RIGHT NOW WHY DOES IT HAPPEN NOW THANKS GOD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i managed to temporarily fix it by downgrading the azure functions vscode extension to v1.13.1....

unbelievably predictable behaviour from microsoft, making buggy software for us poor developers to suffer through

Comment: Wow this also solved my problem. Seems like i embarrassingly downgraded the wrong extension when i tried to solve this problem myself. Big thanks to you for this answer. It is weird how this can even happen after an update but for now this is the correct answer. If anyone knows exactly why this happend please let me know.

Comment: Bug is reported and fix is on the way: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/3967